# How to output current user's AD sAMAccountName to a textbox

Tags: asp.net

I'm designing an eform that submits information into a CSV. I need to display the current user's `sAMAccountName` and the `Datetime.Today` in two of the text fields.

Any idea of how this would be done?

I've been trying: c#

```
public string UserName { get { return Session["UserName"]; } }
```

to:

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" Width="44px" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pre-populate input values in your form in the `Page_Load` event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    UserName.Text = "my value";
    TxtCurrentDate.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just augmenting this quickly with another bit of info, I was originally adding the Page_Load cmds to the codebehind's Page_load event, be sure that all prepopulation of text-boxes is handled on the .aspx page.

All contained within the .aspx

> ```
> protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     txtDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
> }
> ```

```
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" Width="181px" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox></td>
```

Thanks again for the helpful reply mellamokb